# Regex para capturar strings fixas em códigos HTML e JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, regex

Estou fazendo alguns testes automatizados para um projeto *legacy* no modelo MVC, porém existe um requisito para um deles que é de capturar todas as strings fixas nos códigos HTML e JS. Já que a empresa do projeto está passando por um processo de internacionalização de seu conteúdo, transformando suas strings fixas em arquivos de recursos.

Eu fiz essa regex: `([\n]|^)(?<Value>(?!.*?\/\/|.*?@\*|.*?@.*?@|.*?\/\*|.*?<!--|.*?\\\*)([^\n]*?)[áâãàéêèíîìóôõòúûù].*)`

Ela resolve parcialmente meu problema, já que identifica caracteres acentuados no código capturando **SE** não estiverem em comentários (`// , /* , @* , @ , <--`).

Então como não existem funções HTML nem JS que utilizam acentos, posso assumir que essas são strings fixas.

Após fazer isso, consegui identificar algumas páginas que tem strings fixas que devem ser transformadas em arquivos de recursos, porém essa regex não cobre todos os casos.

Gostaria de uma regex que:

- Consiga capturar strings fixas mesmo sem caracteres acentuados nos códigos HTML e JS.
- Ignore os casos de strings em comentários.

> Existiria em alguma dessas linguagens alguma particularidade de
>   sintaxe que poderia me ajudar a delimitar onde a regex deve capturar
>   para identificar essas strings?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? Como assim `strings`? Somente aquelas que estão fora das tags? Quais as possibilidades das `strings` fixas? O que não deve ser considerador? O que o seu `regex` não captura? Poderia adicionar um exemplo da página que está com problemas?

Comment: Essas são algumas informações que podem ajudar a conseguir uma resposta mais rápido.

Comment: @Randrade Vou editar o post para tentar explicar melhor, o que específicamente você não entendeu ou ficou vago? 
as strings que digo são qualquer grupo de caracteres que não são adaptáveis conforme a mudança do idioma, como "funcionario" ou 'sim'.
O que não deve ser considerado são palavras dentro de tags no casos de html como: <não considerar> considerar <\nc>
Meu regex não está capturando comentarios (e deve assim) e strings fixas no código que não tem caracteres acentuados.
Não existe uma pagina que está com problema, é um projeto grande, podem haver centenas de paginas n consideradas

Comment: Então, isso complica um pouco. Para montar o regex você precisa saber ao menos qual o padrão para considerar ou não considerar. Se você falar que tudo que está entre aspas deve ser considerado, é uma coisa. Se falar que tudo que está fora das tags, também é uma possibilidade. Agora, existem outros possíveis casos? Tentar fazer algo genérico assim sem conhecer as possibilidades pode ser complicado.

Comment: esse é o desafio, gostaria de saber se existe alguma particularidade que não consegui enxergar em algumas dessas linguagens que faça um padrão que definiria o inicio e fim da captura da regex. Talvez considerar aspas duplas dentro de um conteudo cercado por tag abrindo e depois fechando

Comment: É complicado, pior que deve ser algo genérico, já que o teste vai varrer mais de 1000 arquivos que foram alterados por dezenas de programadores diferentes

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58602/discussion-between-paz-and-randrade).

Comment: Acho usar REGEX pra isso não é uma boa ideia. Sempre vai ter um caso que não conseguirá cobrir. Eu sugiro tentar algum parser próprio pra html. Veja essa resposta http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/460775

Comment: @EMBarbosa porém como incluir isso nos testes automatizados? E os casos de JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível usar regex sobre HTML.

Repita comigo. Não é possível usar regex sobre HTML.

Escreva em um quadro 100 vezes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    print('Não é possível usar regex sobre HTML.')
}
```

Se você conseguiu usar regex sobre HTML, você usou somente sobre um trecho, ou em um caso muito específico. Porque, no geral, não é possível usar regex sobre HTML.

Não acredite apenas porque eu estou falando. A melhor resposta de todos os tempos no Stack Overflow matriz foi sobre uma pergunta semelhante. Então veja lá mesmo.

## **Não é possível usar regex sobre HTML.**

Porém, como diz a resposta lá na raiz, você pode usar um XML parser.

Comment: É bom reforçar que não é possível usar Regex sobre HTML.

Comment: primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta, além de esclarecedora ela também foi muito engraçada rs. 
Porém acho que deve ser possível de alguma forma, a regex que expus por exemplo funciona e atestou muitas ocorrencias nos códigos em HTML.
SideNote: você poderia ter colocado Stack Overflow Raiz ao invés de Stack Overflow matriz rsrsrs

Comment: @Renan ao invés de zoar com a minha cara poderia ter pelo menos exposto uma solução alternativa rsrsrs

Comment: *Mea culpa*:  você pode usar um XML parser, como diz a resposta no SO raiz.

Comment: @Renan edita sua resposta que marco ela como a correta, só editar e colocar a parte do XML parser que você falou agora.
Cara, não quero ser desrespeitoso nem nada, mas as vezes os usuários mais recentes podem se sentir intimidados com uma atitude de gozação sobre uma pergunta completamente valida como essa. Eu sou de boa, mas só digo isso pra rever seus conceitos aí, pode acabar ofendendo alguém sem querer...

Comment: @Paz eu já tinha editado. Agora, com relação ao tom da resposta, a maioria dos meus colegas e eu nos sentimos intimidados quando a resposta vem muito séria, parece que estou falando com clérigos encapuzados quando a coisa vem limpa e seca. O pessoal no SO raiz, que é onde eu fui criado, tem a mesma atitude, então peço desculpas por este meu mau hábito XD

Comment: @Renan realmente, acho que estou sendo muito nuttela mesmo, valeu e cheers m8