# Como separar tags de uma variável em array PHP

Tags: php

Quero separar tags em um `array` no PHP, mas não consegui encontrar uma forma eficiente ainda.

Quero transformar isso:

```
$variavel="<div><div>texto1<a>texto2</a><b>texto3</b></div>texto4</div>";
```

em

```
$array[0]="texto1";
$array[1]="texto2";
$array[2]="texto3";
$array[3]="texto4";
```

E assim por diante, ou seja quero dispor o texto capturado em um site, em várias `arrays`, para assim tratar ele 1 a 1.

Comment: Para o exemplo dado, fazer [isso](http://ideone.com/AuK7Dt) já produz o resultado esperado, porém acho difícil que funcionará para a real necessidade (pois utilizar regex em HTML é estranho), então acredito que será melhor você [edit] a pergunta e detalhar melhor o que você pretende fazer. O que seria esse texto capturado de um site? Ele segue algum formato? É a página inteira?

Comment: O que quero fazer é um tradutor de alfabetos, tipo o que o google faz com o tradutor de idiomas...
Preciso capturar o texto do body da pagina, e separar o texto entre as tags, e substituir o texto romano pelo texto em grego, ou japones, ou qualquer que seja o alfabeto

Comment: Ah o indice da lista 2 eu esqueci foi um erro de digitacao mesmo hehehe

Comment: Então faça como aconselhei e edite a pergunta adicionando um exemplo real da sua necessidade, pois será necessário, provavelmente, utilizar a classe DOMDocument.

Comment: Mas eu quero fazer isso em php, não é javascript não...
E minha pergunta já está explicando o que preciso fazer, que é transformar uma string html, e capturar o texto das tags dispondo ele em um array com cada pedacinho em uma posição do aray
So preciso saber como é que faço isso. Já tentei muitas coisas mas nada deu certo, como split no caracter <, e usando regex tb não funcionou..

Comment: Seria útil [esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114164/php-regex-pegar-a-tag-html) ?

Comment: DOMDocument é uma classe do PHP, não do JavaScript.

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Regex para capturar strings fixas em códigos HTML e JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203940/5878).

Answer (score 2):

Como comentado, a melhor forma de tratar um texto HTML em PHP é utilizar a classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php). Você pode carregar uma página HTML em um objeto `DOMDocument` da seguinte forma:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Sendo `$html` o conteúdo do arquivo a ser analisado. Como é desejado apenas obter o conteúdo do corpo do arquivo, podemos obter o nó referente ao `body` da seguinte forma:

```
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
```

Sendo `$body` um objeto `DOMNode`. É possível verificar se o elemento possui elementos filhos através do método `hasChildNodes` e percorrê-los através do atributo `childNodes`. Desta forma, podemos criar uma função recursiva que extrai o texto de todos os nós da página:

```
/**
 * Obtém o texto presente em um arquivo HTML, retornando-o em forma de lista.
 * 
 * @param DOMNode $element Elemento de onde será extraído o texto.
 * @param array   $texts   Lista de textos previamente obtidos.
 * @return array Lista de textos obtidos no elemento.
 */
function getTextsOfElements(DOMNode $element, array $texts = [])
{
    // Verifica se o elemento possui elementos filhos:
    if ($element->hasChildNodes()) {
        // Sim, então percorre todos os elementos filhos de forma recursiva:
        foreach ($element->childNodes as $e) {
            // Obtém os textos dos elementos filhos:
            $texts = getTextsOfElements($e, $texts);
        }
    } else {
        // Não, então verifica se o elemento é um texto:
        if ($element->nodeType == 3) {
            // Sim, remove os espaços em branco:
            $text = trim($element->nodeValue);

            // Verifica se o texto não é vazio:
            if ($text) {
                // Sim, então adiciona o texto à lista:
                $texts[] = $text;
            }
        }
    }

    // Retorna a lista de textos:
    return $texts;
}
```

Assim, para obter a lista de textos, basta chamar a função passando o objeto `$body` como parâmetro:

```
print_r(getTextsOfElements($body));
```

Se a entrada for a especificada na pergunta (HTML completo):

```
$html = '<html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        texto1
                        <a>texto2</a>
                        <b>texto3</b>
                    </div>
                    texto4
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>';
```

A saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => texto1
    [1] => texto2
    [2] => texto3
    [3] => texto4
)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/IkBN/1).

Comment: estranho, por algum motivo está dando erro na linha 
function getTextsOfElements(DOMNode $element, array $texts = [])
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
Mas os colchetes aparentemente estão certos

Comment: @MegaAnim, o problema dos colchetes pode ser devido a esse trecho `array $texts = []`. Isso é a forma curta para arrays, introduzido no PHP5.4. Se a sua versão é inferior, será emitido o erro de sintaxe. Nesse casso, corrija para a forma normal `$texts = array()`.

Comment: Daniel, consegui fazer o seu metodo funcionar.... Mas descobri uma coisa, nao posso suprimir as tags, preciso delas, e pelo visto talvez seu modo possa me ajudar... Será que e possivel salvar elas no mesmo array?
Exemplo: texts[0]="<body> <div> <div>"; texts[1]=texto1; texts[2]="<a>"; texts[3]="</a>" .... e assim por diante?

Comment: Andei mechendo com seu exemplo, e descobri um jeito de fazer o que eu quero, só que estou tendo uns probleminhas com as tags do tipo fechada exemplo </div> Eu pego o nome da tag com $tagNome=$e->tagName; E coloco na variavel $tag="<".$tagNome.">"; Depois basta mandar para o $texts[] = $tag; Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que as tags fechadas, aparecem vazias o valor do tagname, o certo era ser /div ou /a etc, mas nao vem valor vazio, será que tem algum jeito de saber qual tag está sendo fechada? –

Comment: Pior que isso, descobri o que é... Esse negocio fecha as tags sem elas realmente estarem sendo fechadas...
Por exemplo <html><body><div>valor<a>conteudo></a></div></body></html>
O problema é que Depois de valor começa um a, esse a faz parte do conteudo da div, porém por algum motivo, esse domnode do php esta criando uma node vazia(que corresponde a um fechamento) Apos valor, e por causa disso a div é fechada antes da hora.

Answer (score 1):

O raciocínio basicamente seria criar uma função que possa substituir todas as tags HTML por uma "tag genérica" vamos chamar assim, e usar o comando `explode`, para transformar essa string em um array. Esse procedimento provavelmente irá criar muitos índices vazios no array, por isso utilizaremos a função `array_filter`, para limpa-lo. Um exemplo prático:

```
<?php
    function remover_vazio($array) {
        return array_filter($array, '_remover_vazio_interno');
    }

    function _remover_vazio_interno($value) {
        return !empty($value) || $value === 0;
    }

    function separaTextoDoHTML($variavel) {
        // Substitui todas as tags HTML por uma tag única
        $variavel = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', '<HTML>', $variavel);

        // Realiza um explode com base na tag única criada, viabilizando separar em um array
        $array = explode('<HTML>', $variavel);

        // Utiliza uma função para filtrar o array e tirar os possíveis indices vazios
        $array = remover_vazio($array);

        // Criar array auxiliar para reordenar
        $arrayAux = array();

        // Percorre o array transferindo para os índices na ordem            
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $arrayAux[] = $value;
        }

        // Retorna valor
        return $arrayAux;
    }
?>
```

O código da função **separaTextoDoHTML** está comentado para maior intendimento, mas o processo é receber uma variável, realizar o `preg_replace`, para criar um item único que possa viabilizar na linha seguinte o `explode`. Isso irá gerar índices vazios e utilizamos a função **remover_vazio** para limpar o array. Um exemplo de uso seria:

```
// Valor informado na pergunta
$variavel = '<div><div>texto1<a>texto2</a><b>texto3</b></div>texto4</div>';

// Chamada da função criada
$retorno = separaTextoDoHTML($variavel);

// Dump da variável retornada para checar seu valor
var_dump($retorno);
```

Isso imprimirá na tela:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'texto1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'texto2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'texto3' (length=6)
  3 => string 'texto4' (length=6)
```

Comment: Leia esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1452488) no [so] sobre utilizar regex e HTML juntos. Para exemplificar: e se uma tag no corpo do arquivo possuir um atributo te contenha o caractere `>`? Por exemplo: `<div data-foo="<teste>" class="red">Texto</div>`. O texto apresentado para esta situação seria `" class="red">Texto` ao invés de apenas `Texto`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Concordo com você, a solução seria falha nesse caso. Mas nos atendo ao problema proposto o código funcionaria, tendo em vista que se estamos falando de um texto com HTML no meio, dificilmente vamos ter o tipo de situação exposta por você. De qualquer forma vou melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Esta pergunta também é interessante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203940/5878

Comment: Olá, estou testando a função, até funciona, mas estou com um probleminha... O array volta com falhas, ele pula numeros, e preciso percorrer ele, tipo num laço for para resgatar os valores, ai da errado, porque tanto o count quanto o sizeof, contam somente os objetos, por exemplo ele retorna 4 elementos, mas nas posicoes 2, 3, 5, 7, ai eu nao consigo percorrer o array.. Tentei limpar ele mas não adiantou $retorno=array_filter($retorno);

Comment: @MegaAnim fiz um ajuste na função, que resolve o problema que você relatou. Teste novamente por favor.

Comment: Como eu disse e está muito explícito nas outras perguntas citadas: usar regex no HTML sempre terá falhas. Além do mais, o jeito que fez para resetar os índices é estranho, pois basta fazer `return array_values($array)`

Comment: Deu certo fazer assim, agora meu tradutor tá quase funcionando, so falta um probleminha que encontrei pra capturar o html do iframe xD

Comment: Consegui resolver tudo agora
primeiro pego a string
document.getElementById("site").contentWindow.document.body.outerHTML
Ai trato ela convertendo em katakana usando o php, via ajax, e com o retorno, transformo ela em objeto html, 
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringConvertida, "text/html");
depois basta setar o body dentro da iframe
document.getElementById("site").contentWindow.document.body=doc.body;